# MOD_OREKA configuration on Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

Has anyone successfully configured mod_oreka? I have been trying but for some reasons control doesn't pass into the module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just did, and stumbled upon your question by googling for something else (related).

Here's what I did:

1. cd into my freeswitch source directory, in **src/mod/applications/mod_oreka** and then **make && make install**, since it wasn't compiled by default the first time.
2. edit the configuration for the module, inside your freeswitch installation directory, open **conf/autoload_configs/oreka.conf.xml** and add:

   ```
   <param name="sip-server-addr" value="1.1.1.1"/>
   <param name="sip-server-port" value="59150"/>
   ```
3. Get into the fs_cli and do **reload mod_oreka** or just restart freeswitch
4. In your calls, make sure to start the application oreka for every call you want to record:

   <action application="oreka_record"/>

These instructions were useful and are the official reference for the module: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_oreka

Hope it helps!